# curl effect for Ebook like Iphone

Tags: android

firstly, forgive me for my bad English. I am developing an App for reading ebook and using Curl effect of harism and  I want when the user switches curled page to left or to right a continue picture will display on left or right side instead of current picture. Example, on the screen are displaying picture 1 on left and picture 2 on right. When I switches curled page to left the screen will display picture 3 and picture 4 instead of pic 2 and pic 3. Can any one help me solve the problem or directions? Here is the link of my source code. 
http://www.4shared.com/file/vyLa1szE/curlEffectAdroid.html?
Thanks and Best Regards

Comment: +1, Nice one, All d best... :-)

Answer (score 1):

The android page flipper is a 2D View which simulates a page curl effect. Without OpenGL, only the android canvas has been used, so that it can be used in any version of Android!

http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/